# Converting a draft script from bash to Make

Tags: makefile

I like to have a script which will fill in front matter when I write new blog posts. In the past, I did this using Bash as seen below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set some variables

export site_path=~/Documents/Blog
drafts_path=~/Documents/Blog/_drafts
title="$1"

# Create the filename

title=$(awk '{print tolower($0)}' <<<"$title")
filename="$title.markdown"
file_path="$drafts_path/$filename"
echo "File path: $file_path"

# Create the file, Add metadata fields

cat >"$file_path" <<EOL
---
title: "$title"
layout: post
tags: 
---
EOL

# Open the file in BBEdit

bbedit "$file_path"

exit 0
```

While not the nicest code, it does the job. As I've moved my other scripts to using Make, I'd like to do the same here. Here the section of my Makefile where I've defined the `draft` rule. I think I've escaped all variables, but it still will not run. Can someone explain where I may be going wrong?

```
SITE_PATH=~/Documents/Blog \
DRAFTS_PATH=~/Documents/Blog/_drafts \
TITLE="$$1" \

TITLE="$$(awk '{print tolower($$0)}' <<<"$$TITLE")" \
FILENAME="$$TITLE.markdown" \
FILE_PATH="${DRAFTS_PATH}/$$FILENAME" \
FILE_PATH="$${FILE_PATH}" \

cat >"$${FILE_PATH}" <<EOL \
--- \
title: "$$title" \
layout: post \
tags: \
--- \
EOL \

# Open the file in BBEdit

bbedit "$${FILE_PATH}" \

exit 0
```

**Update**: For reference, the complete Makefile is [here](https://github.com/chrisfinazzo/blog/blob/master/Makefile) where `draft` simply executes the original shell script.

Comment: It would help if you could show us the actual Makefile. If it's not running there may be syntax or other issues that we can't see from the excerpt you've provided here.

Comment: 1) *Why* are you trying to convert a bash script into a makefile command? 2) Is this the simplest such command that fails?